# How to get firebase data as a array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
public func getAllItems(completion: @escaping (Result<[Item], Error>) -> Void) 
{
    database.child("Items").observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
        guard (snapshot.value as? [[String: Any]]) == nil else{
            completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
            return
        }
        
        var newUrlArray: [Item]  = []
        var newItemArray: [Item]  = []
        for child in snapshot.children{
            if let childSnapshots = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let dict = childSnapshots.value as? [String:Any],
                let title = dict["title"] as? String,
                let content = dict["content"] as? String,
                let itemId = dict["itemid"] as? String,
                let price = dict["price"] as? Int{
                let item = Item(title: title, content: content, itemId:  itemId, price: price, urs: newUrlArray)
                newItemArray.append(item)
            }
        }
        completion(.success(newDataArray))
    })
}
```

My question is how can I get **urls** that shown in picture as an array or is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go one level deeper into your JSON/Snapshot hierarchy to get the URLs.

If I remove the non-URL code for a moment for readability, it'd be something like:

```
for child in snapshot.children{
    if let childSnapshots = child as? DataSnapshot,
        let dict = childSnapshots.value as? [String:Any],
        let urls = childSnapshots.childSnapshot(atPath: "urls").value as? [String:Any],
        ...
    }
}
```

So `urls` above is another dictionary, where you can loop over its keys to get the URL values.